# No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip

Tags: reactjs, npm, tfs, azure-devops, yarnpkg

I created a build definition in vsts with npm build and then I copy the build folder to the drop location.

The build pipeline is working fine

Then I created the release definition and it downloads the files correctly also:

```
2018-08-10T16:29:18.5241580Z Downloading artifact drop from: https://xx.visualstudio.com//_apis/resources/Containers/711976?itemPath=drop&isShallow=true&api-version=4.1-preview.4
2018-08-10T16:29:18.5252684Z Downloading drop/s/build/asset-manifest.json to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\asset-manifest.json
2018-08-10T16:29:18.5253850Z Downloaded drop/s/build/asset-manifest.json to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\asset-manifest.json
2018-08-10T16:29:18.5338277Z Downloading drop/s/build/favicon.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\favicon.png
2018-08-10T16:29:18.5338720Z Downloaded drop/s/build/favicon.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\favicon.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5191236Z Downloading drop/s/build/index.html to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\index.html
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5191520Z Downloaded drop/s/build/index.html to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\index.html
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5195415Z Downloading drop/s/build/manifest.json to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\manifest.json
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5195775Z Downloaded drop/s/build/manifest.json to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\manifest.json
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5198280Z Downloading drop/s/build/service-worker.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\service-worker.js
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5198598Z Downloaded drop/s/build/service-worker.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\service-worker.js
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5704236Z Downloading drop/s/build/css/ionicons.min.css to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\css\ionicons.min.css
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5725284Z Downloaded drop/s/build/css/ionicons.min.css to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\css\ionicons.min.css
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5833575Z Downloading drop/s/build/iconfont/iconfont.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\iconfont\iconfont.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5868415Z Downloading drop/s/build/fonts/ionicons.eot to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\fonts\ionicons.eot
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5901623Z Downloading drop/s/build/fonts/ionicons.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\fonts\ionicons.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5922072Z Downloaded drop/s/build/iconfont/iconfont.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\iconfont\iconfont.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5967502Z Downloading drop/s/build/iconfont/iconfont.ttf to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\iconfont\iconfont.ttf
2018-08-10T16:29:19.5990580Z Downloaded drop/s/build/fonts/ionicons.eot to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\fonts\ionicons.eot
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6014585Z Downloading drop/s/build/iconfont/iconfont.eot to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\iconfont\iconfont.eot
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6041800Z Downloaded drop/s/build/iconfont/iconfont.ttf to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\iconfont\iconfont.ttf
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6082471Z Downloading drop/s/build/fonts/ionicons.woff to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\fonts\ionicons.woff
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6355639Z Downloading drop/s/build/fonts/ionicons.ttf to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\fonts\ionicons.ttf
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6356035Z Downloaded drop/s/build/fonts/ionicons.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\fonts\ionicons.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6609672Z Downloaded drop/s/build/iconfont/iconfont.eot to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\iconfont\iconfont.eot
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6614749Z Downloading drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-128x128.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-128x128.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6649976Z Downloaded drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-128x128.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-128x128.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6691472Z Downloaded drop/s/build/fonts/ionicons.woff to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\fonts\ionicons.woff
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6715380Z Downloading drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-144x144.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-144x144.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6721599Z Downloaded drop/s/build/fonts/ionicons.ttf to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\fonts\ionicons.ttf
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6730634Z Downloaded drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-144x144.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-144x144.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6925986Z Downloading drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-192x192.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-192x192.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.6932585Z Downloaded drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-192x192.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-192x192.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7051155Z Downloading drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-384x384.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-384x384.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7068272Z Downloaded drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-384x384.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-384x384.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7128194Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/css/main.1338bde0.css to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\css\main.1338bde0.css
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7136566Z Downloading drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-72x72.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-72x72.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7139811Z Downloaded drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-72x72.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-72x72.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7210596Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/css/main.1338bde0.css to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\css\main.1338bde0.css
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7331736Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/js/1.f6d2865a.chunk.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\1.f6d2865a.chunk.js
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7336557Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/js/1.f6d2865a.chunk.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\1.f6d2865a.chunk.js
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7384208Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/js/2.194ad0ec.chunk.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\2.194ad0ec.chunk.js
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7388897Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/js/2.194ad0ec.chunk.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\2.194ad0ec.chunk.js
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7493081Z Downloading drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-512x512.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-512x512.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7505060Z Downloaded drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-512x512.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-512x512.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7521694Z Downloading drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-96x96.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-96x96.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7524304Z Downloaded drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-96x96.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-96x96.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7531569Z Downloading drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-152x152.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-152x152.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7544109Z Downloading drop/s/build/iconfont/iconfont.woff to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\iconfont\iconfont.woff
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7561190Z Downloaded drop/s/build/images/icons/icon-152x152.png to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\images\icons\icon-152x152.png
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7583131Z Downloaded drop/s/build/iconfont/iconfont.woff to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\iconfont\iconfont.woff
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7615220Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/js/4.0230ee4e.chunk.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\4.0230ee4e.chunk.js
2018-08-10T16:29:19.7620680Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/js/4.0230ee4e.chunk.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\4.0230ee4e.chunk.js
2018-08-10T16:29:19.8139663Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/media/sign.adf5846b.jpg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\sign.adf5846b.jpg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.8209000Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/media/sign.adf5846b.jpg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\sign.adf5846b.jpg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.8445251Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/media/uk.bc48afcc.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\uk.bc48afcc.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.8451360Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/media/uk.bc48afcc.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\uk.bc48afcc.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.9315367Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/media/france.bcd389de.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\france.bcd389de.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.9316203Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/media/spain.6a9dc11f.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\spain.6a9dc11f.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.9316588Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/media/france.bcd389de.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\france.bcd389de.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.9317287Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/media/spain.6a9dc11f.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\spain.6a9dc11f.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.9430066Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/media/italy.604345b4.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\italy.604345b4.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:19.9430433Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/media/italy.604345b4.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\italy.604345b4.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:20.0800791Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/js/3.06bbf4d1.chunk.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\3.06bbf4d1.chunk.js
2018-08-10T16:29:20.0801318Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/js/3.06bbf4d1.chunk.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\3.06bbf4d1.chunk.js
2018-08-10T16:29:20.0962282Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/js/0.cdfd5bd5.chunk.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\0.cdfd5bd5.chunk.js
2018-08-10T16:29:20.0962659Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/js/0.cdfd5bd5.chunk.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\0.cdfd5bd5.chunk.js
2018-08-10T16:29:20.1118659Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/js/main.03f3e98f.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\main.03f3e98f.js
2018-08-10T16:29:20.1541007Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/js/main.03f3e98f.js to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\js\main.03f3e98f.js
2018-08-10T16:29:20.1566610Z Downloading drop/s/build/static/media/china.4e4d59b7.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\china.4e4d59b7.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:20.1569167Z Downloaded drop/s/build/static/media/china.4e4d59b7.svg to D:\a\r1\a\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build\static\media\china.4e4d59b7.svg
2018-08-10T16:29:21.1552541Z Total Files: 35, Processed: 35, Skipped: 0, Failed: 0, Download time: 3.288 secs, Download size: 1.320MB
2018-08-10T16:29:21.1844380Z Successfully downloaded artifacts to D:\a\r1\a/InnovationInABox-CI
2018-08-10T16:29:21.1897267Z ##[section]Finishing: Download artifact - InnovationInABox-CI
```

But the next step, is to deploy to an Azure web app: but I get this error:

```
2018-08-10T16:29:21.8347426Z Got connection details for Azure App Service:'uiapp'
2018-08-10T16:29:24.0708659Z ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip
2018-08-10T16:29:26.8772211Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/81533918564296
2018-08-10T16:29:26.8855771Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service
```

How can I copy all those files from the build folder (which are not in a .zip file) to Azure webapp?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using "Azure App Service Deploy" task, set the "Package or folder" path to: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build`.
[image]

Comment: I get exactly the same error, but with an updated path: `No package found with specified pattern: d:\a\r1\a\{My-Repo-Name}\drop\s\build`

Comment: Am getting this error `Error: No package found with specified pattern: d:\a\1\s\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build`

Comment: @Eddie, Can you please help me with this? Am getting this error Error: No package found with specified pattern: d:\a\1\s\InnovationInABox-CI\drop\s\build

Answer (score 15):

In my case (build .sln with c# project from azure git) the build was saving the package in D:\a\1\a\ folder (instead of **r1**\a) and I wasn't able to edit the build steps in the UI so I edited the newly added **azure-pipelines.yml** file and **added one more task at the very end:**

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

This copies the .zip package to a "drop" location (r1/a) which the Release Pipeline expects.

​And now the Release Pipeline is finding the file in r1/a folder.

Comment: Neither the accepted answer nor this would work for me. Adding the above task gave me the error `'/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.` during build pipeline and editing the release pipeline to change the directory to D:\a\1\a resulted in the same release pipeline error that OP is getting.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone else experiencing this problem using Azure DevOps, it's useful to turn on debug mode. For your release, define the [pipeline variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables)  `System.Debug`  with value `true`. 
That gave me this output which was much more useful: 
[image]

Now at least I know it's on my target VM and the path is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use wildcards for folder names unfortunately, only for file names. If you're using a 'Copy Files' build task you can put this value in 'Source Folder':
D:\a\r1\a\

and this value in 'Contents':
**\*.zip

Or you can put the full file directories with *.zip. Good luck.

Comment: the answer I dont think its related to my problem, the npm build does not generate a .zip file, however the app deploy action is trying to find a .zip file to be deployed to azure

Comment: Then that string is in your build somewhere I can't imagine that particular format was generated by vsts, is D:\a\r1\a a directory on the local machine where the build succeeds? Are there zip files your build references for tests or data?

Answer (score 0):

First i think you should add artifacts[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc2wG.png) then attach it to the packages[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbhDd.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case (react app deployed as static content to app service) I needed to add a step to archive the build directory before publishing it:

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build' 
    includeRootFolder: false 
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

- publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
  artifact: '$(Build.BuildId)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Azure official document for setting up Pipelines (YAML files) for `Node.js`, `Javascript` apps from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=code

1. Configure the YAML file as below:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: 'build/**' # Pull the build directory (React)
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs: 
    pathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) # dist or build files
    ArtifactName: 'www' # output artifact named www
```

2. On the latest version of `Azure Devops`, edit `Release` under `Pipeline`. Note that `Build` section has been taken off in the latest version (as of June 2020), so some older answers/docs was not working.
   [image]
3. Click on `Deploy Azure App Services` and on the right panel click on `...`(Expand Folder) for `Package or folder` Option
   [image]
4. Under `Linked Artifacts` => `MyProject (Build)` => `www`, select `dist` folder.
   [image]

Save this and then create release, this should solve the error `[error]Error: No package found with the specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

I used the below task in Azure DevOps release `yaml` pipeline for deployment of azure function app and set the package to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` and it worked for me.

```
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: XXXXXXXXX
                  appType: 'functionApp'
                  appName: 'funcapp-test'
                  package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
                  appSettings: 
                  deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use azure template but change vmImage: "windows-latest", When I check logs, find out build command didn't run so I figure out I should change default script of install and build to separate script

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildFolder: 'build'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: |
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm build'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: 'build/**'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    cleanTargetFolder: true

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this again.  What worked for me was modifying "Package or folder" to use Agent.ReleaaseDirectory.  Screenshot below, may it save someone else the angst.

[image]