# Is there a way to edit azure-pipelines.yml after creating the pipeline?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy a project through Azure DevOps. I have already set up a subscription group and resource group, and have created the pipeline, but when I create a new release it gives me this error: 
"No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip"

This error occurs during the “Deploy Azure App Service” phase of the deployment process. I've read that a way to fix this is to configure the root folder's yml file, but I don't see an option to edit the file. The build definition will only let me view yml files. Is it possible to edit the yml after the pipeline has been created? I already know what needs to be done to fix this error, I just can't access what I need to do so. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

So after following Frank's instructions, it seems that I might not even have the yml file. When I edit the build it just shows the tasks in my build definition (image linked below), and I don't have the yml file in source control either, yet I do have a pipeline. Does it matter that I'm using TFVC?

[Build Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kof9O.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\‌\*\*\‌\*.zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790735/no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d-a-r1-a-zip)

Comment: You edit the file in source control, the same way you would edit any other file. That's the entire point of YAML pipelines: They're in source control.

Comment: pretty much what Daniel said. its just a text file. you can edit it in any way you like and commit it back

Comment: @sbarry,Now YAML doesn't support TFVC repository. I have updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you created a pipeline, you have two ways to edit the YAML files.
The first one is, click the edit icon in build pipeline and then you can edit the YAML files directly.

[image]
The second one is, after you created a pipeline with yaml, the yaml files will be in your Azure repo. You can edit it in your Azure repo, too.

[image]

**Updated**

Now, YAML doesn't support TFVC repository. According to your image, you are using classic editor to define a build pipeline not YAML. That is why you don't have the yml file. You can edit the file option on the build definition webpage directly.