# Error: No package found with specified pattern: d:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created a pipeline definition in Azure Devops to deploy an angular app to Azure

I have already added the stepa for publishing in the pipeline definition file which is azure-pipilines.yml file `"- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1"`, but the error still persist and Release fails.

> Error: No package found with specified pattern: d:\a\r1\a***.zip

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try which has already mentioned in the past:

- Make sure the artifacts are zipped for release to download,
- If you are using "Azure App Service Deploy" task, set the "Package or folder" path to: `**$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\CI\drop\s\build**` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51833033/6049604) .
- Define the [pipeline variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables) `**System.Debug**` with value true. which gives output which is much more useful:

Additional reference:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4637

Hope it helps.