# No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s\**\*.zip

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm following the instructions on MSDN to set a pipeline to do 2 things

1. Build
2. Deploy to Web App created under my subscription

The current error i am receiving is

***No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s***.zip***

but after some changes i receive a similar error about the location.

Here is my 2 YAML files

```
`trigger:
- master


pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'


steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1


- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'


- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'`
```

Deploy YAML

```
`trigger:
- master


pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'


steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1


- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'


- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'NEW_SUB'
    appType: 'webApp'
    appName: 'Testing'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'`
```

Every thread i have read i have tried a different path but it doesnt seem to work and i get an error about the file not found. I have also used the default config provided when i create a pipeline so i thought that would have limited the error factor.

What am i missing?

Also would it be correct to remove some of duplicate code from each YAML i.e. Nuget packages?

I have seen these threads and have attempted majority of the fixes but im not sure if i missed a critical step somewhere?

[Azure DevOps pipeline release Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117244/azure-devops-pipeline-release-error-no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d)

[No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790735/no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d-a-r1-a-zip)

i do see a file under artifacts when i look at the logs (under drop)

Comment: Refer my SO answer to resolve your error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440816/no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d-a-1-websitebr/76472534#

Comment: - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'subscription'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'valleyweb-app'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'
Add '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip' in the package: and run the yaml code again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You publish your build result here:

```
/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip"
```

By default, it is located here: `c:\agent_work\1\a`

However, you are trying to deploy this package:

```
package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

In this case, the build agent tries to check this folder: `c:\agent_work\1\s`

Here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Update your last step to:

```
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'NEW_SUB'
    appType: 'webApp'
    appName: 'Testing'
    package: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/WebApp.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'`
```

or

```
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'NEW_SUB'
    appType: 'webApp'
    appName: 'Testing'
    package: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'`
```

Comment: One final question on this, could I reduce any of the YAML tasks in the deploy one?

Comment: @KeithViking no.. your deployment yaml contains the minimum... but if you do not want to run unit tests, you may remove VSTest@2.